# Get messages sent to external combo box

Tags: vb.net, winapi, spy++

I know the handle of the ComboBox of an **external** program.

With this code:

```
Dim Count As Integer = NativeMethods.SendMessage(ComboHwnd, CB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0)
If Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To Count - 1
        itemLength = NativeMethods.SendMessage(ComboHwnd, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, i, 0)
        itemText = New String(" "c, itemLength)
        itemLength = NativeMethods.SendMessage(ComboHwnd, CB_GETLBTEXT, i, itemText)
        Debug.Write("-" & itemText)
    Next
End If
```

I can get the items of the external ComboBox. The problem is that I get the items **after** them are inserted and **sorted**, while I need to get the items **before** they are inserted in the ComboBox and consequently sorted.

**Spy++** does this job without problems. if I check the messages sent to the ComboBox by Spy++, I can see the items one by one while they are sent, so BEFORE they are inserted in the ComboBox and sorted. **How can I do this job in VB.Net?**

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that you may be able to use the [`NativeWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) to intercept window messages in another process. Use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) to get the ComboBox's thread ID to hook.

Comment: The system only marshals standard Windows messages across process boundaries. All other messages (like `CB_*`) need to be manually marshaled by you.

Comment: And to do that, you will need to use `OpenProcess()`, `VirtualAllocEx()`/`VirtualFreeEx()`, and `(Read|Write)ProcessMemory()` to work with the string buffers used by the CB messages, because the buffers used have to be valid within the process that owns the ComboBox.

Comment: Ty for the answers... I will now try to understand HOW put into practice your suggestions...........